# How do I detect which JavaScript method changed my HTML element?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm working with JS library which seems to incorrectly position SVG elements inside my DIV. How can I debug which part of the library causes this? What's the procedure or useful code?

Comment: Have you tried browser debugger?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: Have you tried Developer tool for browser

Comment: I'm working on IE11's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

While using a debugger would be the way to go, you could also make the value a setter and then use that to break into the point where the value changes. For instance with

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" style="color: red;">My color changes</div>
```

and

**Script**

```
Object.defineProperty(document.getElementById("a").style, "color", { set: function (x) { alert(x); } });
document.getElementById("a").style.color = "blue";
```

just put a breakpoint on the `alert(x)` and you'll directly break one level away from the point where the value is changed (just go down the callstack)